# Operations only with textbox c#

Tags: c#, math, calculator

I'm trying to make a simple calculator using only textbox.
I Thought my code was correct, but the result is almost always wrong.

This is the code:

```
void TextBoxPercorsoTextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBoxPercorso.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBoxAgilitySmallVelocita.Text))
            textBoxAgilitySmallTps.Text=(Convert.ToDecimal(textBoxPercorso.Text)/Convert.ToDecimal(textBoxAgilitySmallVelocita.Text)).ToString();
    }

    void TextBoxAgilitySmallVelocitaTextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBoxPercorso.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBoxAgilitySmallVelocita.Text))
            textBoxAgilitySmallTps.Text=(Convert.ToDecimal(textBoxPercorso.Text)/Convert.ToDecimal(textBoxAgilitySmallVelocita.Text)).ToString();
    }
```

I have tried to do some attempts. For example I tried to do 10/5, but the result is 0.5. Only with 10/10 the result is correct.

Can you help me, please?

Comment: Could it be that you need to invert your arguments?

Comment: @npinti You're right! But I don't understand why. I have to do length/speed, so I did textboxLength/textboxSpeed. If I invert my arguments, the result is correct

Comment: Make sure that you did not swap the text boxes on the display, thus you would be reading from one field when you are thinking that you are reading from the other.

Comment: I checked, but the names are correct. I don't know. Thank you, anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Try avoiding *magic button* antipattern (extract a method); do not repeat youself (copy + paste):

```
   private void ComputeSmallTps() {
     decimal perCorso;
     decimal smallVelocita;

     // first, parse arguments...
     if (!decimal.TryParse(textBoxPercorso.Text, out perCorso) ||
         !decimal.TryParse(textBoxAgilitySmallVelocita.Text, out smallVelocita)) {
       // invalid input data, e.g. "bla-bla-bla"
       textBoxAgilitySmallTps.Text = "???"; 

       return;
     }

     try { 
       // ...then compute: put the right formula here 
       // put break point here, check smallVelocita and perCorso values
       decimal result = smallVelocita / perCorso;

       textBoxAgilitySmallTps.Text = result.ToString(); 
     }
     catch (ArithmeticException) {
       // Division by zero, overflow 
       textBoxAgilitySmallTps.Text = "???";
     }
   }

   ...

   void TextBoxPercorsoTextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
     // Just a simple call, no complex logic here
     ComputeSmallTps();
   }

   void TextBoxAgilitySmallVelocitaTextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
     ComputeSmallTps();
   }
```